windows container scanning against vulnerabilities
I'm looking for command-line tools that can scan Windows containers for vulnerabilities. My primary focus is to integrate the tool into a CI/CD pipeline.
Any suggestions?
tried trivy, but this is not supporting windows containers, at least their open sourced version. Maybe aqua can do that, idk.
sysdig cli scanner is also created only for linux containers.

Searching for software recommendations is off-topic. You may try our sister site https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ Note that your question should be improved by providing more details before posting there.
